# why kafka-0.9 multiple consumers in same group consume the same messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

the profile:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9092  
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=home  
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false  
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=10  
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-commit-interval=100  
spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-max-wait=10000  
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual_immediate
```

the consumers:

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions={@TopicPartition(topic = "aaa",partitions = {"0"})},group = "home")  
public void doConsume(ConsumerRecord a){  
    log.info("000000 received kafka message:{},offset={}",a.value(),a.offset());  
}

@KafkaListener(topicPartitions={@TopicPartition(topic = "aaa",partitions = {"0"})},group = "home")  
public void doConsume1(ConsumerRecord a){  
    log.info("111111 received  kafka message:{},offset={}",a.value(),a.offset());  
}
```

the producer:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/2 * * * * ?")  
public void doProduce(){  
  for(int i =0;i<5;i++){  
     kafkaTemplate.send("aaa","say my name!"+ UUID.randomUUID());  
  }  
}
```

log in console:

111111 received kafka message:say my name!3d0e7171-cae1-44c9-8a9a-f21289160108,offset=42141
000000 received kafka message:say my name!3d0e7171-cae1-44c9-8a9a-f21289160108,offset=42141
111111 received kafka message:say my name!90851ac4-1e5f-4ac8-93c9-72acd64ce529,offset=42142
000000 received kafka message:say my name!90851ac4-1e5f-4ac8-93c9-72acd64ce529,offset=42142
111111 received kafka message:say my name!4d0fa93d-c7e7-4f44-beba-bfa6c25aee12,offset=42143
111111 received kafka message:say my name!d1707959-0be2-4ec1-a81d-86ef211cb73d,offset=42144
000000 received kafka message:say my name!4d0fa93d-c7e7-4f44-beba-bfa6c25aee12,offset=42143
111111 received kafka message:say my name!79cfea0d-548d-437d-bd05-8b65a27f9e9a,offset=42145
000000 received kafka message:say my name!d1707959-0be2-4ec1-a81d-86ef211cb73d,offset=42144
000000 received kafka message:say my name!79cfea0d-548d-437d-bd05-8b65a27f9e9a,offset=42145

Actually,the two consumers consume the same messages according to the messages in console.
thank you.

Comment: Who send information to topic `topic = "spyfool"` ?

Comment: oh,that's a mistake of editing,actually the two consumers listen the same topic.

Comment: Probably SpringBoot merges them into one subscription to Kafka, receives message and then gives it to both consumers. To verify this guess you can check Kafka broker using command line tools and see if there is one consumer or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When giving the Kafka Listener a Topic Partition , you tell it to use manual assignments and not using the subscribe mechanism...

assign does not work with the consumer group mechanism

So you have two consumers assigned to topic `aaa` partition `0`... so both are getting same messages

Btw. the right annotation property to set group is `groupId`

Comment: The version of spring-kafka  that I used is 1.0.0,there is no annotation property of 'groupId' in this version,TT.And thanks for your answer that resolve my question,and you're right,that's the problem.Thanks a lot.